# Output SQL query as an array

Tags: sql, arrays, wordpress

I am retrieving records from a tables in a WordPress database using the following....

```
global $wpdb;
echo '<table>';
$sellers = get_users('blog_id=1&orderby=nicename&role=sellers');
foreach ($sellers as $seller) 
    {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . $seller->user_login . '</td>';

    $count1 = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM wp_mymeta2 a JOIN wp_mymeta1 b ON b.id = a.my_id WHERE a.value = '$seller->user_login' AND b.date_posted LIKE '%2014-04-19%'" );
    echo '<td>' . $count1[0]->count . '</td>'; 

    $count2 = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM wp_mymeta2 a JOIN wp_mymeta1 b ON b.id = a.my_id WHERE a.value = '$seller->user_login' AND b.date_posted LIKE '%$2014-04-18%'" );
    echo '<td>' . $count2[0]->count . '</td>';

    $count3 = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM wp_mymeta2 a JOIN wp_mymeta1 b ON b.id = a.my_id WHERE a.value = '$seller->user_login' AND b.date_posted LIKE '%2014-05-17%'" );
    echo '<td>' . $count3[0]->count . '</td>'; 

    echo '</tr>';
    }
echo '</table>';
```

This works great and is returning the data I want and echoing it into a table.

I now want to have the data placed into an array instead so I end up with...

```
var $example_data = array(
            array(
                'seller'    => '$seller',
            'date'      => '$date1',
                'count'     => '$count_result',
            ),
        array(
                'seller'    => '$seller',
            'date'      => '$date2',
                'count'     => '$count_result',
            ),
        array(
                'seller'    => '$seller',
            'date'      => '$date3',
                'count'     => '$count_result',
            ),
        );
```

Does anyone have an example they can point me in the right direction of something similar being achieved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use array_push function inside your foreach loop

```
global $wpdb;
echo '<table>';
$sellers = get_users('blog_id=1&orderby=nicename&role=sellers');
$arrSellers = array();

foreach ($sellers as $seller) 
{
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>' . $seller->user_login . '</td>';

$count1 = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM wp_mymeta2 a JOIN wp_mymeta1 b ON b.id = a.my_id WHERE a.value = '$seller->user_login' AND b.date_posted LIKE '%2014-04-19%'" );
echo '<td>' . $count1[0]->count . '</td>'; 

$count2 = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM wp_mymeta2 a JOIN wp_mymeta1 b ON b.id = a.my_id WHERE a.value = '$seller->user_login' AND b.date_posted LIKE '%$2014-04-18%'" );
echo '<td>' . $count2[0]->count . '</td>';

$count3 = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM wp_mymeta2 a JOIN wp_mymeta1 b ON b.id = a.my_id WHERE a.value = '$seller->user_login' AND b.date_posted LIKE '%2014-05-17%'" );
echo '<td>' . $count3[0]->count . '</td>'; 

echo '</tr>';

 //add whatever you want to $arrSellers using array_push

}
echo '</table>';
```